# Possible values of grating constant

Tags: waves

I need help with a question regarding diffraction gratings. It goes something like this:

Assume that you have a diffraction grating. When you shine light of different wavelength through this grating it will give different amounts of maxima. Let's say the grating has to satisfy the following: If we shine light of wavelength $\lambda_1$ we get $3$ maxima and if we shine light with wavelength $\lambda_2$ we get $5$ maxima. What values of the grating constant are possible given the criteria stated above?

I have tried to solve this using the grating equation, $d\sin a = k\lambda$ where I set $k = 1$ for 3 maxims and $k = 2$ for $5$ maxima and then look at what different values for the angle $a$ give. With $90^{\circ}$ as the maximum angle. However, using this method I find that $d > \lambda_1$ for $3$ maxima, and $d > 2\lambda_2$ for $5$ maxima which seems wrong to me. Is this answer wrong?

I would really appreciate all help!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a physics question and has an answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230752/total-number-of-primary-maxima-in-diffraction-grating